# Can I change the order of verification and code review in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

We are using gerrit for our project. We have a jenkins job to run compile and test, then it give a verification score. 
After I push a patch set, the jenkins job starts to run and reviewers start to review code. But the job may failed while the reviewers are doing code review. So is it possible that a jenkins job verification process before code review.
In other word, reviewers receive code review notification only after verification is passed

Comment: When and how are reviewers added? A stock Gerrit instance with no plugins doesn't add any reviewers automatically so the solution to your problem would simply be "well, don't add reviewers until the test results are in then" so I'm assuming you have some plugin that adds the reviewers.

Comment: I guess the [reviewers plugin](https://gerrit.it.here.com/plugins/reviewers/Documentation/index.html) is used?

Answer (score 3):

If it's not enough just to ask the reviewers to hold their reviews until the patch set is verified, and you really need to hide a code review until it has ben successfully built by Jenkins, you can make use of Drafts:

- configure Jenkins to kick off a build when a Draft is published
- publish your code review as a [Draft](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#_refs_drafts)
- add Jenkins as a [Reviewer](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-receive-pack.html#_examples) when you push so it can see the draft being published
- when the build succeeds, publish your draft for the reviewers to see